# My implementation of EqualsIgnoreCase in C is not working

Tags: c, string, standard-library

I am currently attempting to program a sort of database in C.

When I create a new character for the database, it should not have the same name as any other character, case-insensitive - so, if "Amy Bob Carol" exists, I should not be able to add a new user "aMy boB cArOl".

So, this is my approach, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
DBPerson* create_character(char* name)
 {
   DBPerson* person = (DBPerson*)malloc(sizeof(DBPerson);
   if (alreadyInDB(name))
    {
     free(person);
     return null;
    }
   strcpy(person->name, name);
   person->friendship = 0;
   person->spouse=NULL;
   addToAllPeople(person); //this adds them to the master list of all people
   return person;
 }
```

The helper functions alreadyInDB and isSame are as follows:

```
int isSame(char* a, char* b)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STR_LEN && a[i]!='\0' || b[i]!='\0'; i++)
 {
  
  if (tolower(a[i]) != tolower(b[i]))
  {
     return 0;
  }
 }
 return 1;
 }

int alreadyInDB(char* name)
{
 DBPerson* tmp = allPeople;
 while(tmp!=NULL)
 {
  if(isSame(name, tmp->person->name))
   return 1;
  tmp = tmp->next;
 }
 return 0; 
}
```

I am importing all necessary libraries - ctype.h, string.h, stdlib.h, stdio.h
Yet if I run it and try

```
  DBPerson* so =create_character("StackOverFlow");
  DBPerson* s2 =create_character("sTacKOverFlOW");
```

both characters are successfully made.

I have spent hours looking over this but cannot find any answer. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: `while(tmp!=NULL)` That looks like a potential infinete loop. Where do you update the `tmp` pointer? If that is not the problem then please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - that is, smallest amount of complete code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also note that the code you've provided will also treat "abc" and "abcd" as identical.

Comment: @kaylum - thanks, I didn't notice this - added in the part where I update the tmp pointer. I'll begin working on the minimal verifiable example.

Comment: @BillLynch thanks - I'll work on that now that I see it.

Comment: Have you tried printing your Master list to see all values are added correctly?

Comment: Also you need `a[i]!='\0' || b[i]!='\0'` instead of `a[i]!='\0' && b[i]!='\0'`

Comment: @Pranavappu thanks, I'll change that part. I did print the master list and they're all there.